# Populate contact form field from link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a website that has multiple html portfolio pages. Each page has a link to the contact.html page. What I'm trying to do is get the 'subject' line of the contact form populated by an id I've attached to the the link on each page. For example, if a user is on '38mmSpruce.html' and they click the 'get in touch with us about this item' link, when the contact.html page loads, the subject line of the contact form is pre-filled.
I've searched in vain for 3 days for a solution; I've tried onClick events, I've tried to use the '_GET' function in php, I've tried adding string queries to the anchors, but the truth is, I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I know the code is scrappy and missing loads of important validation data, but I just need to know how to make this possible so that I can move on. Honestly, it's ruining me. This is my contact.php form

```
<?php
//I've changed these to dummies just to post this. It works with my email
$from = 'Demo contact form <example@example.com>';
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <example@example.com>';
//I tried to change this to '_GET['subject'] but it didn't work
$subject = 'Subject';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email', 'subject' => 'Subject', 'message' => 'Message');
$okMessage = 'Contact form succesfully submitted. Thank you, I will 
    get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please 
    try again later';
try {
    $emailText = "You have new message from contact 
    form\n=============================\n";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $encoded;
} else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
?>
```

And my html form looks like this

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" name="contact-form" role="form">
    <div class="messages"></div>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="form_name">Name *</label>
                <input id="form_name" type="text"
                name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name *"
                    ="    ">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *"     ="    ">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="form_subject">Subject *</label>
                <input id="form_subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter the subject you'd like to discuss *" rows="1"     ="    ">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message here *" rows="4"     ="    "></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send
                message">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="text-muted">
                    <strong>*</strong> These fields are     .
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If there is anything at all that you can offer to help me solve this seemingly simple puzzle, please help me. 
Oh, total Noob, obvs. Sorry about that. But I am learning!

Comment: What does the html/code for the links on the other pages look like? Using `$_GET` won't help if the calling page isn't passing the subject through. Also, both your description and the comment in your code say `_GET` - I'm not a PHP guy, but isn't it `$_GET`? (Also, check the html for your form: you have a closing `</textarea>` tag on an `<input>` element.)

Comment: In your form you have specified the method as 'POST', so all the values will be sent/accessible tp/in `$_POST['nameofthevalue']`! So your forth line should be `$subject = $_POST['subject'];`

Comment: btw: `_GET` is not a function, it's a global var, defined by php itself, so you allways have to have a `$` in front just like for `$_POST['myvarname']`

Comment: further information: values submitted via a form usually land in `$_POST` unless you specify any other (like GET). Values in `<a href='link.php?value=1'>` land in `$_GET`

Comment: Hi everyone. Jeff - I changed that 4th line. Thank you.

Comment: nnnnnn-thanks for that. I had removed it earlier but cmd-z'd it back in by mistake when i was removing some other code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change your form processing code at all if you're trying to preload the subject into the form html. Assuming I'm understanding your code correctly, this is what you should do:

The link on your `38mmSpruce.html` page should look something like this:

```
http://example.com/contact.html?subject=the+subject+of+the+message
```

Notice the URL encoded `subject` query string.

Then, in your form HTML (**not** the php you wrote to process the form data) you would simply set the value of the input field:

```
<input id="form_subject" name="subject" class="form-control"
    placeholder="Please enter the subject you'd like to discuss *" 
    value="<?php echo $_GET['subject']; ?>" 
    required="required"/>
```

Notice how the `subject` query parameter is accessed through `$_GET` then echoed into the value of the input.

Note: You had a typo in your code (a trailing `</textarea>`) that I fixed... this could also be part of your issue!

Note 2: This is also assuming you have your html files being processed by php, which is definitely not typical. You might need to change `contact.html` to `contact.php`.

Comment: Thanks The Maniac. Thanks so much for replying. Your solution ALMOST worked - the subject field was populated, but with <?php echo $_GET['subject']; ?>, rather than the value of that command. Thanks for fixing that closing div. I had done it, but then Cmd/Z'd it back in by mistake. In my php form the method is $_POST, so I tried changing the $_GET to $_POST, but I get the same result either way. We're so close! Any more help on this would be hugely appreciated. Thanks everyone